# XSL 1.0 line breaks missing in output

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an XML file for which I have to frame XSL so that my ETL job can process it. Here is what i need.

Input XML

```
<FS_Sub_Investment_Team>
    <Report Name="REPORT">
        <MeetTheTeamTableHeading Label="TEAM" />
        <MeetTheTeamTable>
            <Rows>
                <Row ManagerData="ABC EFGHI XYZ" />
                <Row ManagerData="ABC PQRST XYZ" />
            </Rows>
        </MeetTheTeamTable>
        <MeetTheTeamNote></MeetTheTeamNote>
    </Report>
</FS_Sub_Investment_Team>
```

Current XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Bio>
        <BioText>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Row/@ManagerData" mode="concat"/>
        </BioText>
    </Bio>
</xsl:template>
```

Current Output :

```
<Bio><BioText>ABC EFGHI XYZABC PQRST XYZ</Bio></BioText>
```

My expected output is: With line break (or) with space between the two element values, please give me both solutions.

```
<Bio><BioText>ABC EFGHI XYZ
ABC PQRST XYZ</Bio></BioText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Bio>
        <BioText>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Row">
                <xsl:value-of select="@ManagerData" />
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </BioText>
    </Bio>
</xsl:template>
```

To insert a space instead of a new line, use:

```
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i tried it work as expected but when i use <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> I am getting 48 line break before the actual value. Any solution please..

Comment: I don't know what "48 line break" means. You can see the above working here: http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQgi

Comment: Mic, I should reiterate the statement, when i use <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>   in the XSL i am getting Leading and Trailing "line breaks" after my ETL job process the XML. When I use <xsl:text></xsl:text>  i am getting Leading and Trailing "Space" after my ETL job process the XML. I need help in eliminate those.

Comment: @saravanankrishnasamy I am afraid I still don't know what you mean. Did you see the link above? Is the result there not the result you asked for?

Comment: Yes Mic, I see the expected result in the link you provided. But when i run my ETL job after placing the same code in XSL file, I am getting the output with Leading and Trailing new line/space (when I use '&#10;' or ' ' respectively). I need to know if i have to handle Leading and Trailing in the same XSL piece code.I can handle it in ETL job but, I am more interested in getting the XSL solution.

Comment: I don't know how to help you, because I don't understand what you're talking about.